# JSON File Format issue

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift

I have been grappling with JSON for a couple of days and realised I am making a basic error.  When I have a JSON file like below my code just below it works perfectly:

```
{"team": [
        {
        "name": "Manchester United FC",
        "code": "MUFC"
        },
        {
        "name": "Swansea City",
        "code": "SWA"
        }
        ]
}
```

Code that works with above JSON file:

```
func jsonParsing()
{
    let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("teams", ofType: "json")!

    var data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: nil)!

    var dict: NSDictionary!=NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


    for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("team") as NSArray).count ; i++
    {
        arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("team") as NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
    }



}
```

However, when my JSON file does not have quote marks for the titles as per below it causes a "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" issue:

```
{team: [
        {
        name: "Manchester United FC",
        code: "MUFC"
        },
        {
        name: "Swansea City",
        code: "SWA"
        }
        ]
}
```

So, you may ask why don't I simply use quotes so it works?  Well, I am getting the JSON information from a website so have to use that format.  For full details on the original file format checkout:

http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams

So, is there a simple setting I can use so it uses my JSON file without the need for all the double quotes?

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Comment: JSON dictionary keys are strings and *must* be enclosed in quotation marks. – However, I cannot see where a key without quotation marks occurs in the JSON that you linked to, *that* actually is valid JSON.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax.  (And shame on you for not having done this already.)

Comment: (When viewed as a web page the site you reference appears to lack quotes, but when you view the actual page source the quotes are there.)

Comment: Hello Hot Licks, I did study it but I just could not understand why it looked like it worked without quotes.  Turns out I have a chrome extension to view JSON files which meant I didnt realise they were actually there.  When I clicked "view source" it was evident they were there.  So confusion over. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those quotes are must for JSON to work. http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: Purely my mistake regards a JSON chrome viewer extension. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
{
    //let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("teams", ofType: "json")!

    //var data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMapped, error: nil)!

let url2 = NSURL(string: "http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams")

let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url2!)

var dict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: nil, error: nil) as NSDictionary

    // var dict: NSDictionary!=NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary


    for var i = 0 ; i < (dict.valueForKey("teams") as NSArray).count ; i++
    {
        arrDict.addObject((dict.valueForKey("teams") as NSArray) .objectAtIndex(i))
    }



}
```

But now I am even more confused as everyone says the original file is not vaild :/  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: The JSON from http://api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams is valid, but the second JSON in your question is invalid. How are they connected?

Comment: Sorry, but I though the second JSON in the question was the same as the JSON from api.football-data.org/alpha/soccerseasons/354/teams website.  As in the keys dont have use quote marks.  Sorry if I have made a mistake in my thinking.

Comment: The keys in the JSON from that website *are* enclosed in quotation marks. So there is actually no problem at all.

Comment: I am so so sorry, I have a JSON viewer in chrome that made it looked they were not in quotes.  After clicking "view source" it is evident what my error was.  Many thanks, Alan.